# How to get the value against the value selected in text box?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to know that when I select any value from dropdown box it shows it's price in next field.

Example: if I select snacks from the dropdown menu then it show its price in next field by fetching its price from database in PHP. Items are also fetched from database.

Here is how I want when select a particular value:

[image: Here is how I want when select a particular value]

Here is the code for fetching data from the database:

```
<?php
$eb = "SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName FROM employees";
$res = mysql_query($eb);
$no_records = mysql_num_rows($res);
if($no_records > 0)
{?>
    <select name="EnteredBy" id="EnteredBy"><?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
         echo '<option value='.$row['EmployeeID'].'>'.$row['LastName'].",".$row['FirstName'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should help you out. All you need to do is write an onchange function to update your "next field" with the value of the option selected.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeValue() {
            var price = document.getElementById('items').options[document.getElementById('items').selectedIndex].value;
            document.getElementById('price').innerHTML= '$'+price;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="changeValue();">
    Select Item:
    <select id="items" onchange="changeValue();">
        <option value="5">Snack</option>
        <option value="1">Soda</option>
        <option value="10">Meal</option>
    </select>

    <br/><br/>
    Price:
    <div id="price">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```